# Fullscreen slider image appears cropped

Tags: javascript, html, css

The fullscreen slider image I put on my website seems partially cropped on various platforms (mobile, small screen, etc). I am trying to fit and stretch it on my homepage and would like it to look the same (with its fullsize) on any platform. Tried many methods according to my search on web, but couldn't find any solutions.

Here is the part of the code:

```
<section class="bannercontainer">
        <div class="fullscreenbanner-container">
            <div class="fullscreenbanner">

                <ul>
                    <li data-transition="parallaxvertical" data-slotamount="5" data-masterspeed="1000" data-title="Slide 1">
                        <img src="~/img/index/slider/slider-05.jpg" alt="slidebg1" data-bgfit="cover" data-bgposition="center" data-bgrepeat="no-repeat" >
```

Here is the related css part:

```
.fullscreenbanner-container {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0; }
  .fullscreenbanner-container .tp-bullets.preview4 {
    opacity: 1 !important;
    height: auto !important; }
    @media (min-width: 992px) {
      .fullscreenbanner-container .tp-bullets.preview4 {
        bottom: 30px !important; } }
  .fullscreenbanner-container .tp-bullets.preview4 .bullet {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) !important;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    width: 6px !important;
    height: 6px !important;
    border: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) !important;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 14px !important;
    margin-left: 0 !important;
    margin-bottom: 0px !important;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s, border-color 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.2s, border-color 0.2s;
    -ms-transition: background-color 0.2s, border-color 0.2s;
    -o-transition: background-color 0.2s, border-color 0.2s;
    transition: background-color 0.2s, border-color 0.2s;
    float: none !important; }
  .fullscreenbanner-container .tp-bullets.preview4 .bullet:hover, .fullscreenbanner-container .tp-bullets.preview4 .bullet.selected {
    box-shadow: none !important;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) !important;
    width: 14px !important;
    height: 14px !important;
    border: 2px solid white !important;
    margin-right: 10px !important;
    margin-left: -4px !important;
    margin-bottom: -3px !important; }
  .fullscreenbanner-container .tparrows.preview4 .tp-arr-iwrapper {
    display: none !important; }
```

Here is how it looks on mobile right now:
[image: mobile]
Here is how it looks on chrome browser right now:
[image: browser]
Here is the real-size image:
[image: realsize]

Comment: Please provide the css code related to the image.

Comment: @Sinisa I added the css as well

Answer (score 2):

You can try 'background-size: cover' for this.

**Syntax**

```
background-size: auto|length|cover|contain|initial|inherit;
```

The attached link has the sample code for your reference. https://jsfiddle.net/jv92788r/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you can get a perfect result here but have you tried the backgound-size cover property?
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

```
div {
    background-image:url('smiley.gif');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First I would remove the slider on mobile, most of my clients ask me to delete the slider on smaller res because the slider content usually is not visible like on higher res. Second solution is to have different slider images that will fit better on mobile. Right now the offers on banners are not that visible on smaller resolution like 360px. The problem on bigger resolution like 1920 is that the images are too small. For example the first image is 1200x600px and the other 3 images are 1000x500px. And you default slider height is 745px. That's why the images dont look good. Try to make the images bigger to fit the slider container and you should have half of the problem done :)